# How can I parse an array in a PDF using Python?

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

I want to parse a PDF in Python. Currently I'm using `PyPDF2.pdf.PageObject.extractText()`, but the text is "all in one". In the file the text is in an array, so what can I do to separate each cell's content ?

##### Current result

```
>>> file_in.getPage(0).extractText()
"Tous grades (7 parcours) - Gergy Esc - 18/07/2021RESULTATS - Agility (Grade 1) - Catégorie A - Classe SeniorJuge : WATTECAMPS Philippe - Obstacles : 15 - Longueur : 155 m - Vitesse : 2.98 m/sec - TPS : 52 sec - TMP : 103 secClas.Dos.Nom du ChienRace du chienConducteurClub / RégionaleTempsVit.Ev.PénalitésQual.Brevetsecm/sec>TPSParc.Total13NANA WELCOMTERRIER JACK RUSCOEUR ODELOT LILIANECC NIVERNAIS / BOURGOGNE38.734.0055.00EXC24JANACROISETORRES KARINAAMICALE DIJONNAISE DES SP48.323.211010.00TBON 1PIN-UPCHIEN DE BERGER LIOCHON SABRINACC D'AROMAS / FRANCHE-COELI 2SUPREME JUSTSTAFFORDSHIRE BLAGRANGE GHISLAINECLUB D'AGILITY DE SAINTE EUELIExcellentsTrès bonsBonsNon classésEliminésAbandons1 (25 %)1 (25 %)0 (0 %)0 (0 %)2 (50 %)0 (0 %)PROGESCO Version 21.05.11Imprimé le 24/01/2022 à 17:39:33Page 1 / 1"
```

##### Expected result

```
>>> file_in.getPage(0).extract()
["Tous grades (7 parcours) - Gergy Esc - 18/07/2021", "RESULTATS - Agility (Grade 1) - Catégorie A - Classe Senior", "Juge : WATTECAMPS Philippe - Obstacles : 15 - Longueur : 155 m - Vitesse : 2.98 m/sec - TPS : 52 sec - TMP : 103 sec", "Clas.", "Dos.", "Nom du Chien", "Race du chien", "Conducteur", "Club / Régionale", "Temps", "Vit.", "Ev.", "Pénalités", "Qual.", "Brevet", "sec", "m/sec",">TPS", "Parc.", "Total", "13", "NANA WELCOM", "TERRIER JACK RUS", "COEUR ODELOT LILIANE", "CC NIVERNAIS / BOURGOGNE", "38.73", "4.00", "55.00", "EXC", "24", "JANA", "CROISE", "TORRES KARINA", "AMICALE DIJONNAISE DES SP", "48.32", "3.21", "10", "10.00", "TBON", "1", "PIN-UP", "CHIEN DE BERGER", "LIOCHON SABRINA", "CC D'AROMAS / FRANCHE-CO", "ELI", "2", "SUPREME JUST", "STAFFORDSHIRE B", "LAGRANGE GHISLAINE", "CLUB D'AGILITY DE SAINTE EU", "ELI", "Excellents", "Très bons", "Bons", "Non classés", "Eliminés", "Abandons", "1 (25 %)", "1 (25 %)", "0 (0 %)", "0 (0 %)", "2 (50 %)", "0 (0 %)", "PROGESCO Version 21.05.11", "Imprimé le 24/01/2022 à 17:39:33", "Page 1 / 1"]
```

##### PDF File

[image: PDF File]

Comment: "In the file the text is in an array" I don't understand what this means. Are you under the impression that, because the PDF *has lines drawn in graphically*, that this should tell you something about the structure of the text that was extracted? PDF is very much not designed for this kind of thing. It is designed to allow for accurate image rendering, not to keep content neatly organized inside the file. It certainly does not have "arrays" of text internally.

Comment: Like the documentation tells you: `Locate all text drawing commands, in the order they are provided in the content stream, and extract the text. This works well for some PDF files, but poorly for others, depending on the generator used. This will be refined in the future. Do not rely on the order of text coming out of this function, as it will change if this function is made more sophisticated.` PDF stores *text drawing commands* - it will say to put some text somewhere on the page, many times, possibly with other things between. The library has to *guess* what "order" they should be in.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I think there isn't only one text command in this file, but PyPDF2 return them "all in one".

Comment: What I am trying to tell you is that this is like if you had a pile of hamburgers, and you wanted to get the cow back.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel OK, I'm trying to find an other way to get my data, without using PDF.

Comment: A Google preview :
`RESULTATS - Agility Standard - Catégorie A - Classe Senior. Juge : JEANCLAUDE Philippe - Obstacles : 16 - Longueur : 180 m - Vitesse : 3.16 ...`
How can I get the same result using Python ? In this preview each text cell is separated by a dot...

Comment: I've found the `pdftotext` library, I think I can close this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`pdftotext`](https://pypi.org/project/pdftotext/), I can get the text content of the PDF file :

```
>>> import pdftotext
>>> pdf = pdftotext.PDF(open("file.pdf", "br"))
>>> print(pdf[0])
['Concours Classique - Wihr Au Val - Ecvm - 29/07/2018', 'RESULTATS - Agility 3 - Catégorie A - Classe Senior\nJuge : JEANCLAUDE Philippe - Obstacles : 21 - Longueur : 215 m - Vitesse : 4.22 m/sec - TPS : 51 sec - TMP : 108 sec', 'Clas. Dos. Nom du Chien\n1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6', '13\n106\n49\n61\n74\n79\n29', 'Race du chien', 'Conducteur', 'Club / Régionale', 'HERMES\nEPAGNEUL NAIN CON LAFFAY GUILLAUME\nDELISSE NOIRE\nCHIEN DE BERGER D REINHARDT ANNABELLE\nGALEOTTI BETHANY JCHIEN DE BERGER D MATHIEU DOMINIQUE\nJOUKY\nTERRIER DU REVERE ETEVENOT ALICE\nIRON BLACK\nCHIEN DE BERGER D REINLE JENNIFER\nHOLLYWOOD HILLS O CHIEN DE BERGER D SCHALLER CELIA\nELONA\nCHIEN DE BERGER D WITTNER BERNARD', 'EGUENIGUE - CECBN / FRANCHECHATENOIS - CCCA / BAS RHIN\nTHIONVILLE - TCCT / LORRAINE\nBRECHAUMONT - SCB / HAUT RHI\nVILLAGE NEUF - CUCCF / HAUT RH\nVILLAGE NEUF - CUCCF / HAUT RH', 'Temps\nsec\n43.81\n43.88\n44.06\n45.09\n45.18\n46.72', 'Vit.Ev.\nm/sec\n4.91\n4.90\n4.88\n4.77\n4.76\n4.60', 'Pénalités\n>TPS\nParc.\nTotal', '5', '5.00', 'LUTTERBACH - TCCL / HAUT RHIN', 'Excellents', 'Très bons', 'Bons', 'Non classés', 'Eliminés', 'Abandons', '6 (85.71 %)', '0 (0 %)', '0 (0 %)', '0 (0 %)', '1 (14.29 %)', '0 (0 %)', 'PROGESCO Version 00.00.00', 'Imprimé le 29/07/2018 à 11:30:49', 'Qual.\nEXC\nEXC\nEXC\nEXC\nEXC\nEXC\nELI', 'Page 1 / 1', '\x0c']
```

It's not perfect, but I think it is the best result.